# How to get this simple regex-parser to catch a Boolean expression?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I am trying to understand parser combinators with Scala, and have written the following:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

class SimpleParser extends RegexParsers {

  def operand: Parser[String] = "[A-Za-z]+".r ^^ {_.toString}

  def operator: Parser[String] = "OR|AND".r ^^ {_.toString}

  def term: Parser[String] = (("(" ~> (operand ~ operator ~ operand) <~ ")")) ^^ {
    case o1 ~ operator ~ o2 => o1 + " " + operator + " " + o2
    case _ => " "
  }


  def expression: Parser[String] = (operand | term | (operand ~ operator ~ term))^^ {
    case str:String => str
    case operand ~ operator ~ term => operand + " " + operator + " " + term
  }
}

object ParserTest extends SimpleParser{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     println(parseAll(expression, "A").get)
     println(parseAll(expression, "(A OR C)").get)
     println(parseAll(expression, "A AND (A OR C)").get)
  }
}
```

The first two prints works find, while the last one causes:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No result when parsing failed at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$NoSuccess.get(Parsers.scala:181)
at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$NoSuccess.get(Parsers.scala:167)
at ParserTest$.main(ParserTest.scala:31)
at ParserTest.main(ParserTest.scala)
```

I thought the last sentence would match the (operand ~ operator ~ term) pattern in "expression". Can someone explain me why my pattern is wrong, and maybe show the write one to match the last print statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're not properly handling the result of `parseAll`.  If you were, you'd see that on the last example, it was returning a `Failure` with the message

```
[1.3] failure: end of input expected

A AND (B OR C)
  ^
```

The problem here is you have your parsers inside `expression` in the wrong order.

When creating a disjunction of parsers (uisng `|`), you always have to start with the "greediest" parser.  In other words, what's happening here is that `operand` by itself is succeeding to parse the "A" and parsing ends.  However, `parseAll` sees that parsing has succeeded but there is still input left, so it returns the above error.

If you reverse the order of the 3 parsers, so it looks like:

```
def expression: Parser[String] = ((operand ~ operator ~ term) | term | operand)^^
```

they are now properly ordered and all 3 examples work.

Comment: Thank you. I did not think about that as a problem.